# Removing proxy settings on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: github, proxy, ubuntu-12.04

I had proxy set when I was using my college WiFi. Later I disabled it through the System Settings GUI. However when I tried to clone a github repo on the terminal it was failing due to connection timeout. Although the proxy is disabled when i ran this code in the terminal,

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

It showed this,

```
http_proxy=http://172.16.0.16:8080/
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=libappmenu.so
https_proxy=https://172.16.0.16:8080/
```

I'm guessing this means the proxy settings are still active. Please tell me how to get rid of this as my current internet connection does not have proxy and because of this I'm not able to use github through the terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your current session, you can [unset those environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables):
([`man unset`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/unset.1posix.html))

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Check also in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` if you are not setting those variables at login.

Those variables could be also define system-wide: check `/etc/environment` or the `/etc/profile.d` folder content.